# Attempting to model a roof

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a roof of a cabin. I added a loop cut to the model and tried to extrude the edge but it creates a flat plane instead of moving the whole roof up like the tutorial showed.

[image]

What it looks like with the loop cut

[image]

What it looks like after I extrude the loop cut

Comment: I don't know the tutorial, but I suggest you watch it again and pay close attention. I'm sure that it doesn't show that you should have selected the complete loop cut edge around the house. And I don't know if it really has to be extruded or if they use a different method.

Comment: what tutorial? How did he do it in that tutorial? This is not how it works, extruding of the loopcut this way will give you face from each one of those edges

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you had extruded an intersecting loop cut in the z-axis when you clearly wanted to make a simple roof. All you have to do is select the top edge in your edge loop and press <kbd>G</kbd> and then press <kbd>Z</kbd>. Now you have a basic roof attached to a cabin-like model. Here`s a GIF to support this answer.

[image]